# What is more common "von Mal zu Mal" or "Mal für Mal"?

Tags: usage

What is the most common way to say *from time to time* between *von Mal zu Mal* and *Mal für Mal*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=from%20time%20to%20time&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) and [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=from%20time%20to%20time) have some good suggestions for *from time to time*; but *von Mal zu Mal* and *Mal für Mal* are not among those.

The obvious (and suitable) translation is: *von Zeit zu Zeit*.

The other suggestions are common, too. Personally, I often use and hear *ab und zu* as well as *hin und wieder*.

*Von Mal zu Mal* and *Mal für Mal* are listed in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mal), but they both are imho not really common. That's why you can hardly tell which of these two words would be "the most common way".

Also see this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=von%20mal%20zu%20mal%2C%20mal%20f%C3%BCr%20mal%2C%20von%20zeit%20zu%20zeit%2C%20hin%20und%20wieder%2C%20ab%20und%20zu&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvon%20mal%20zu%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvon%20Mal%20zu%20Mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVon%20Mal%20zu%20Mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvon%20mal%20zu%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmal%20f%C3%BCr%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMal%20f%C3%BCr%20Mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmal%20f%C3%BCr%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cvon%20zeit%20zu%20zeit%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvon%20Zeit%20zu%20Zeit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVon%20Zeit%20zu%20Zeit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chin%20und%20wieder%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhin%20und%20wieder%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHin%20und%20wieder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cab%20und%20zu%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bab%20und%20zu%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAb%20und%20zu%3B%2Cc0).

---

As I accidentally answered in German first, here's the German version:

[Leo](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=from%20time%20to%20time&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) und [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=from%20time%20to%20time) haben gute Vorschläge für *from time to time*; *von Mal zu Mal* und *Mal für Mal* sind aber nicht darunter.

Die naheliegendste (und auch passende) Übersetzung ist: *von Zeit zu Zeit*.

Alle anderen Vorschläge sind auch durchaus gängig. Persönlich verwende und höre ich häufig *ab und zu* sowie *hin und wieder*.

*Von Mal zu Mal* und *Mal für Mal* findet man zwar im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mal), kommen aber meines Erachtens nicht so häufig vor. Daher kann man nicht sagen, welche von diesen beiden denn nun "the most common way" wäre.

Siehe dazu dieses [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=von%20mal%20zu%20mal%2C%20mal%20f%C3%BCr%20mal%2C%20von%20zeit%20zu%20zeit%2C%20hin%20und%20wieder%2C%20ab%20und%20zu&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvon%20mal%20zu%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvon%20Mal%20zu%20Mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVon%20Mal%20zu%20Mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvon%20mal%20zu%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmal%20f%C3%BCr%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMal%20f%C3%BCr%20Mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmal%20f%C3%BCr%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cvon%20zeit%20zu%20zeit%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvon%20Zeit%20zu%20Zeit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVon%20Zeit%20zu%20Zeit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chin%20und%20wieder%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhin%20und%20wieder%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHin%20und%20wieder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cab%20und%20zu%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bab%20und%20zu%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAb%20und%20zu%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

*from time to time* is usually translated as *von Zeit zu Zeit*.

Examples:

> Ich besuche von Zeit zu Zeit meine Familie.

You would not use *von Mal zu Mal* here.

*von Mal zu Mal*, *mit jedem Mal* and *Mal für Mal* as translation for *with every time* seem to be used equally often.

Examples:

> Deine Kochkünste werden von Mal zu Mal besser.

You would not use *von Zeit zu Zeit* here.

Answer (score 0):

"Von Mal zu Mal" is used to express a development, as in "sein Gesundheitszustand wurde von Mal zu Mal besser". Translating "from time to time", you can say "ein oder das andere Mal", "von Zeit zu Zeit", but there are many other possibilities like "ab und zu", "gelegentlich", "manchmal", "hin und wieder", etc.